# Exception creation stateless session bean

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I'm trying to create an JaveEE project using EJB upon glassfish.
I have an Exception when trying to run it.

There is a entity bean:

```
User.java
@Entity
    public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

EJB session:

```
package com.supinfo.courses.EJB;

import com.supinfo.courses.EJB.local.UserFacadeLocal;
import com.supinfo.courses.entities.User;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;


@Stateless
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User> implements UserFacadeLocal {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "4JVA-Courses-ejbPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public UserFacade(EntityManager em, Class<User> entityClass) {
        super(entityClass);
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UserFacade() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public User findByCredentials(String email, String password) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
        Root<User> from = cq.from(User.class);
        cq.where(cb.equal(from.get("email"), email));
        cq.where(cb.equal(from.get("password"), hashPassword(password)));
        TypedQuery<User> query = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        List<User> resultList = query.getResultList();

        // return first user that match or null
        return (resultList.isEmpty()) ? null : resultList.get(0);
    }


    @Override
    public void create(User entity) {
        // encrypt password (sha1)
        entity.setPassword(hashPassword(entity.getPassword()));
        super.create(entity);
    }


    public String hashPassword(String password) {
        String sha1 = "";
        try {
            MessageDigest crypt = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            crypt.reset();
            crypt.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            byte[] byteHash = crypt.digest();

            try (Formatter formatter = new Formatter()) {
                for (byte b : byteHash)
                    formatter.format("%02x", b);
                sha1 = formatter.toString();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new Error("Unable to hash password");
        }

        return sha1;
    }

}
```

And a service for using it:

```
@Stateless
public class UserService {

    @EJB
    public UserFacade userFacade;


    public User registerUser(User user) {
        userFacade.create(user);

        return user;
    }


    public User loginUser(String email, String password) {
        User foundUser = userFacade.findByCredentials(email, password);

        return foundUser;
    }


    public boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
            emailAddr.validate();
        } catch (AddressException ex) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And finally the related servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "LoginServlet", urlPatterns = {"/login"})
public class LoginServlet extends AbstractServlet {

     @EJB
     UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String error = null;
        // Parse login informations
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");


        User user = null;
        if (email == null || password == null) {
            error = "Missing field";
        } else if(!userService.isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
            error = "Invalid email address";
        } else if(password.length() < 7) {
            error = "Password too short";
        } else {
            user = userService.loginUser(email, password);
            if (user == null) {
                error = "Bad Credentials";
            }
        }

        if (error != null) {
            //redirect with error data to jsp
            request.setAttribute("error", error);
            render("login", request, response);
        } else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
            forward("/courses/list", request, response);
        }

    }

}
```

The stacktrace indicate:

```
    Avertissement:   Context path from ServletContext: /4JVA-Courses-war differs from path from bundle: 4JVA-Courses-war
Grave:   EJB5070: Exception creating stateless session bean : [UserService]
Avertissement:   EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UserService, method: public boolean com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService.isValidEmailAddress(java.lang.String)
Avertissement:   javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy447.isValidEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
    at com.supinfo.courses.services.__EJB31_Generated__UserService__Intf____Bean__.isValidEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
    at com.supinfo.courses.servlets.authentication.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session into class com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session into class com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 70 more

Avertissement:   StandardWrapperValve[LoginServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet LoginServlet threw exception
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:435)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:2516)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy447.isValidEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
    at com.supinfo.courses.services.__EJB31_Generated__UserService__Intf____Bean__.isValidEmailAddress(Unknown Source)
    at com.supinfo.courses.servlets.authentication.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:700)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:246)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer._getContext(StatelessSessionContainer.java:430)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.CreateException: Could not create stateless EJB
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:514)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.access$000(StatelessSessionContainer.java:97)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer$SessionContextFactory.create(StatelessSessionContainer.java:698)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session into class com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultInjector.inject(DefaultInjector.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.JCDIServiceImpl.injectEJBInstance(JCDIServiceImpl.java:257)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.injectEjbInstance(BaseContainer.java:1683)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.createStatelessEJB(StatelessSessionContainer.java:475)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session into class com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:138)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:613)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Exception resolving Ejb for 'Remote ejb-ref name=com.supinfo.courses.services.UserService/userFacade,Remote 3.x interface =com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade,refType=Session' .  Actual (possibly internal) Remote JNDI name used for lookup is 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:188)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.ComponentEnvManagerImpl$EjbReferenceProxy.create(ComponentEnvManagerImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:745)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:183)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade#com.supinfo.courses.EJB.UserFacade not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:237)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:204)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:478)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: Is this really the error on deployment?

Comment: No i edit the post, it's when i access: POST /login

Comment: Any other previous errors?

Comment: No, it's only happend when i try to access `isValidEmailAddress()` which doesn't throw any error itself ... I must admit i'm stuck with that for quite a time and any try i gave to solve it failed sadly :(

Comment: so if you removed the UserFacde from this EJB does it still fail?

Comment: can you paste complete stack trace?

Comment: Edit for stack trace.
Removing _UserFacade_ allow me to use _UserService_ partially. So i'm searching deeper to debug _UserFacade_. I will update thread to show complete UserFacade class.

Comment: Are you deploying the whole app in a single war or ear and war two different packages ?

Comment: As an _Enterprise Application_ (war+ejb), i also try to go for a single war (i was thinking maybe the build was corrupted) and i still had the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, also i didn't totally understood the logic.

#### From EJB Spec 3.1 - 4.9.2.1:

> **Session Bean Superclasses**
>
> A session bean class is permitted to have superclasses that are themselves session bean >classes. However, there are no special rules that apply to the processing of annotations or the deployment descriptor for this case. For the purposes of processing a particular session bean class, all superclass processing is identical regardless of whether the superclasses are themselves session bean classes. In this regard, the use of session bean classes as superclasses merely represents a convenient use of implementation inheritance, but does not have component inheritance semantics.
>
> For example, the client views exposed by a particular session bean are not inherited by a subclass that also happens to define a session bean.
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class A implements Foo { ... }
>
> @Stateless
> public class B extends A implements Bar { ... }
> ```
>
> Assuming Foo and Bar are local business interfaces and there is no associated deployment descriptor, session bean A exposes local business interface Foo and session bean B exposes local business interface Bar, but not Foo.
>
> Session bean B would need to explicitly include Foo in its set of exposed views for that interface to apply. For example:
>
> ```
> @Stateless 
> public class A implements Foo { ... }
>
> @Stateless
> public class B extends A implements Foo, Bar { ... }
> ```

I my case, refractoring project and removing Interfaces worked.